# $A \in SL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ is automorphism of $(F*)^{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Let $A \in SL(n,\mathbb{Z})$, containing every matrix over integers with determinant $\pm1$. And let $F$ be a field, and $F^{*}$ is a multiplicative group of a field $F$. Now define  $m_{A}:(F^{*})^{n} \to (F^{*})^{n}$ by 
$$x=(x_1, \cdots, x_n) \mapsto A.x= (x_{1}^{a_{1,1}} \cdots x_{n}^{a_{n,1}}, \cdots,x_{1}^{a_{1,n}} \cdots x_{n}^{a_{n,n}} ),$$ where $a_{ij}$ is element of $A$. How can I show that $m_{A}$ is automorphism?

Usually, I tried to show my works before asking a question on the StackExchange. However, in this time, I don't have any clue. Could you give me some hint?

Comment: Usually $\mathrm{SL} (n,ℤ)$ is defined to be the group of matrices of determinant $1$ only.

Comment: Also, do you know what a $ℤ$-module is?

Comment: Some direct computation may show that $SL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ is acting on $(F^{*})^n$ as a group.

Comment: @k.stm Yes, I know $\mathbb{Z}-$module.

Comment: @OsamuIkeuchi Thank you! I try to show that it is a group action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to switch notations: $F^×$ is an abelian group $(F^×,·,1)$. But we actually don’t need to know that it is the multiplicative group of some field. In linear algebra, we are instead used to “$+$” and “$0$”, so writing “$·$” and “$1$” will only confuse us about what is linear and what not.

So let’s take instead a more general abelian group $H = (H,+,0)$. Then we have a map
$$\operatorname{Mat}_{n×n}(ℤ) → \operatorname{End}(H^n),~A ↦ m_A$$
given by setting for $A = (a_{ij})_{ij}^{n×n}$,
$$m_A \colon H^n → H^n,~(x_1,…,x_n)  ↦ ({a_{11}}x + … + a_{1n} x_n,…,a_{n1}x_1 + … + a_{nn}x_n).$$
If you write $(x_1, …,x_n)$ as a column $x = \Big[\begin{smallmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{smallmatrix}\Big]$, you probably recognize this as the matrix product $m_A \colon x ↦ Ax$. You probably also already *know* that $m$ then defines a monoid homomorphism, that is: $m_{AB} = m_A ∘ m_B$ for $A, B ∈ \operatorname{Mat}_{n×n}(ℤ)$

In particular, the identity matrix $E_n$ is sent to the identity $m_{E_n} = \mathrm{id}_H$ and if $A$ is invertible with inverse $B$, so is $m_A$ with inverse $m_B$. Thus, $m$ restricts to a *group homomorphism*
$$m \colon \operatorname{GL}_n (ℤ) → \operatorname{Aut}(H^n),$$
the image of an invertible matrix being an invertible endomorphism of $H^n$.

Setting again back $H = F^×$, the map $m_A$ becomes for $A = (a_{ij})_{ij}^{n × n}$,
$$m_A \colon (F^×)^n → (F^×)^n,~(x_1,…,x_n) ↦ (x_1^{a_{11}}·…·x_n^{a_{1n}},…,x_1^{a_{n1}}·…·x_n^{a_{nn}})$$
which is – up to a permutation of the entries – the map you are intersted in.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the clear explanation. I didn't catch that it is matrix product.